# Interpreting the output of structural break detection function

Tags: r, econometrics

I'm using **sctest** function in strucchange package to check if there are breaks in my series.

I would like to understand how to interpret its result, in an example i get:

```
> g <- sctest(cars$dist~cars$speed+0)
> g

    Recursive CUSUM test

data:  cars$dist ~ cars$speed + 0 
S = 0.9147, p-value = 0.06379
```

What does it mean, are there breaks?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The null hypothesis is that there are no structural breaks. Since your p-value is $0.063$ you can say that data does not disprove null hypothesis at $0.05$ significance level, i.e. there are no structural breaks. I would however hesitate to declare that there are truly no structural breaks without any further investigation.

Comment: two things: (1) 0.063 is above 0.05 so why can i accept it? maybe should be below..no? (2) what other investigation should i do? what methods? thank you!

Comment: better CUSUM Method?

Comment: Null hypothesis is rejected if the p-value is less than the significance level. So if significance level is 0.05 and p-value is 0.063 null hypothesis should be accepted. Now null hypothesis is that there are no structural breaks. As for further investigation, there are a lot of things you can do, but they depend on your initial purpose of applying the test.

Comment: How do you define better?

Comment: mpiktas I don't know you told me to do other investigation and i thought that this method is not very good.

Comment: @ mpiktas, I'm testing forex prices time series.

Comment: @Ecotime, no method is perfect. Usually different methods should be used in different situations. Hence it is always prudent not to base your decision on one method only, unless you have a good reason for that. You did not give any context, hence the disclaimer attached.

Comment: @Ecotime, what is the purpose of the testing? If you want only a quick check, then you can perfectly assume that there are no structural breaks, but be prepared to revisit this assumption.

Comment: mpiktas after this check I will use ADF and Johansen procedure for the cointegration, so surelly there are other tests after this. But, the other don't check structural breaks, for this reason i'm looking for a good method for breaks...(forex prices)

Comment: mpiktas, what do you think about ZIVOT? maybe i should use both?

Comment: My teachers always get mad if we say "accept the null". They always seem to prefer "Do not reject the null".

Comment: @Brandon, I've changed the wording. I though about it and I came to conclusion, that I use expression accepting null as a slang, I usually mean the correct version, but the correct version is too long :)